# How to split a String value into a String Array?

Tags: java, split

I have a String variable `columnNames` which includes the column names of a grid I am trying to sort.
`String columnNames = "To, From, RHVAC Technician Schedules Complete, MST Schedules Complete"`.

I am looking to split this into a String Array with 4 values. I have tried the following line of code :

```
String[] headersAllJobs = columnNames.split(" ");
```

However, when I run this, the commas are still stuck to the value so I have for example `"To,"` and `"From,"`. How can I split these values without the commas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String columnNames = "To, From, RHVAC Technician Schedules Complete, MST Schedules Complete";
String[] headersAllJobs = columnNames.split(", ");
```

Answer (score 4):

use the below code:

```
String[] split = columnNames.split(", ");
```

now 
 the value of **split[0]** will be **To**
 
**split[1]** will be **From**
 
**split[2]** will be **RHVAC Technician Schedules Complete**
 
...
 
...

Answer (score 2):

According to [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), you can use `split` method to do it.

```
String columnNames = "To, From, RHVAC Technician Schedules Complete, MST Schedules Complete";
String[] headersAllJobs = columnNames.split(", ");
```